# Infinite-dimensional affine space in algebraic geometry and algebraic topology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, soft-question, topological-vector-spaces

In topology, there are of course many different infinite-dimensional topological vector spaces over $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$. Luckily, in algebraic topology, one rarely needs to worry too much about the distinctions between them. Our favorite one is:

- $\mathbb R^\infty = \cup_{n < \omega} \mathbb R^n$, the "smallest possible" infinite-dimensional space

Occasionally one might also use:

- $\mathbb R^\omega = \prod_{n < \omega} \mathbb R$
- $\ell_2(\mathbb R)$
- If one is doing serious geometry, using differential equations or something, one might start to use more interesting TVS in a serious way, more like an analyst.
- If things get really crazy, one might see "uncountable-dimensional" analogs of these, but it's pretty rare for this to come up in my (probably quite skewed!) experience.

Typically, an algebraic topologist needs such a space either to receive an embedding from a smaller space, or to collect together all finite-dimensional vector spaces in one place. When fancier vector spaces come up, it's usually because one is interfacing with other fields, and one ends up actively looking for ways to simplify them.

**Question 1:** Just how misleading was that synopsis of the use of infinite-dimensional vector spaces in algebraic topology?

One thing that algebraic geometry shares with algebraic topology is an emphasis on fairly "finite objects" -- this is probably even more the case in algebraic geometry since even mapping spaces can have relevant finiteness properties. So my guess would be that infinite-dimensional vector spaces are likely used in algebraic geometry in a similar way to how they're used in algeraic topology.

**Question 2:** Just how off-target is that guess -- that algebraic geometry uses infinite-dimensional vector spaces in the "same" way as algebraic topology?

More specifically, in algebraic geometry, there are natural candidates for analogs to the first two spaces above:

- $\mathbb A^\infty_0 = \cup_n \mathbb A^n$ (colimit taken as a scheme, if it exists)
- $\mathbb A^\infty = \cup_n \mathbb A^n$ (an ind-scheme)
- $Spec k[x_0,x_1,\dots] = \mathbb A^\omega = \prod_{n<\omega} \mathbb A^1$ (as pointed out by Wojowu in the comments, this [product is preserved](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0CNH) by the inclusion of affine schemes into schemes.)

I would guess that these schemes are non-isomorphic (probably $\mathbb A^\infty$ is not compact, and in particular not affine?) as in topology, but that the difference between them is typically inessential for "most" algebro-geometric concerns, as I think it is in algebraic topology.

**Question 3:** Is that correct? Are $\mathbb A^\infty$, $Spec k[x_0,x_1,\dots]$, and $\mathbb A^\omega$ non-isomorphic, but with differences which are inessential "in practice"?

**Question 4:** Are there other infinite-dimensional vector spaces which come up in algebraic geometry?

I also suspect that in algebraic geometry, some of the roles played by $\mathbb R^\infty$ in algebraic topology are really more appropriately analogized to the roles of $\mathbb P^\infty$, e.g. to receive embeddings from varieties. I'm not sure how to fit that issue into the above broad statements, but it probably means that I should be asking about $\mathbb P^\infty = \cup_n \mathbb P^n$ and $ Proj k[x_0,x_1,\dots]$ too.

Comment: I don't think your $\mathbb A^\infty$ has a natural scheme/variety structure. However, it is an [ind-scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ind-scheme). On the other hand, I'm fairly sure $\operatorname{Spec}k[x_0,\dots]$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb A^\omega$.

Comment: @Wojowu thanks, I intended the "$\cup_n$" to be interpreted as a colimit in the category of schemes, but I am aware that this category lacks many limits and colimits, so you may well be right that it can only be interpreted as an ind-scheme. If both interpretations make sense, then we have potentially 4 infinite-dimensional vector spaces to consider. OTOH I'm not certain -- $Spec k[x_0,x_1,\dots]$ is the product of $\omega$-many copies of $\mathbb A^1$ in the category of affine schemes, but it's not immediate to me that it is so in schemes. I'd worry about ultrafilters somehow creeping in...

Comment: @TimCampion In motivic homotopy theory it's the ind-scheme $\mathbb{A}^\infty$ that plays the role usually played by $\mathbb{R}^\infty$. Although, admittedly, trying to embed positive-dimensional varieties in it is problematic.

Comment: @DenisNardin -- thanks-- I suppose there it's playing more the role of "collecting all the finite-dimensional vector spaces" like topologists do in topological K-theory, rather than being all about embedding things?

Comment: @TimCampion Well it's also useful to embed 0-dimensional things (or bundles of such), you can get surprisingly much mileage out of that

Comment: One thing that confuses me is that I want to object to $Spec k[x_0,x_1,\dots]$ as an infinite-dimensional vector space on the grounds that it is compact, but of course $\mathbb A^1$ is itself compact, which is already confusing.

Comment: @TimCampion It might be compact, but it's certainly not [proper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_morphism)

Comment: The ind-scheme $\mathbb A^\infty$ and the infinite-type scheme $\mathbb{A}^\omega$ are both used and I would say that they are really essentially different in practice. Both arise in geometric Langlands for example where you want to consider something like the $\C$-vector space $\mathbb C((t))$ as an algebro-geometric object over $\mathbb C$. This has both an ind and a pro direction, which are treated differently when you want to study things like sheaves, D-modules, etc. on such objects. (See work of Raskin, Beraldo...)

Comment: There are infinite-dimensional compact vectors spaces in ordinary topology, too (over finite fields). Other words, I concur entirely with Sam Gunningham - both come up a lot in geometric Langlands and related fields, and I haven't seen any other examples (unless you count the product of those two as an example).